# Installing ubuntu 20.04 on MacBook 2,1 (2007)

Tags: uefi, macbook

The MacBook 2007 is one of those exceptions that can run amd64 Linux but can only be booted with a 32 bit EFI instead of the 64 bit EFI that comes with the installer.

So, How can I do this ?

Comment: All 2007 MacBooks have 64 bit EFIs. There are 2006 MacBook 2,1 models with 32 bit EFIs. See [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/index-macbook.html). All MacBook 2,1 models can hold 4 GB of RAM, but can only access the first 3 GB. [Ubuntu recommended minimum system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Desktop_Edition) are for 4 GB of RAM. Perhaps you might consider Kubuntu or Xubuntu which requires less memory.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the MacBook 2007 can only read from a 32 bit EFI booting  partition. The Ubuntu 20.04 installer iso uses a 64 bit EFI booting partition. But you can add the 32 bit EFI to the installer and make it think it includes it. This way you can make it install Ubuntu amd64 properly.

Do the following:

1. Flash the Ubuntu USB installer on a USB. I used Rufus for that on a Windows 10 PC.
2. Copy content of this repository into the root of the installer USB: https://github.com/faalbers/EFI_32_BIT
3. Don't install Ubuntu but first try it on the USB so we can install an additional package missing first.
4. Once in the "Try Ubuntu" interface, start a terminal and run the following commands to install grub 32 bit package so that the installation will be successful at the end. You need an internet connection to find the package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install grub-efi-ia32
   ```
5. Now install Ubuntu and it will work.

Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

For Intel Macs with a 32 bit EFI and 64 bit processor, installing a BIOS booting 64 bit Linux may be possible. Depending on the installation method, Linux may be able to use a GUID Partition Table (GPT) even when BIOS booting. However, the Mac will need to be hybrid partition in order to enable BIOS booting. Installation would probably be easier using a DVD, however using a flash drive may be possible. This would require a Linux installer that can be EFI booted, but install a BIOS booting GRUB. In the past, Debian installers were able to do this and may still be able to do so. Once you have a BIOS booting GRUB, you can use this to BIOS boot other Linux installers and then replace Debian. As you can image, the whole proceedure can get complicated. You can post a comment if you wish to pursue this further.